# How to update existing date and insert new date in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem in updating date. My first table is

```
DONOR
donor-nic----username-----status
111----------ali----------available
222---------usman--------notavailable
```

My second table is

```
DONATION
donation_id------donor_nic-----date---
1----------------111----------2012/03/04
2---------------111-----------2012/06/07
3----------------111---------2012/07/08
4----------------222---------2012/03/03
```

Now I am editing profile like:

- change date:  2012/07/07
- change status: available/not available

I want to do the following:

- If a donor is editing profile/status.. select the date that already exists in donation table with his donor_nic then it will update his date.
- If donor select new date that does not exist in donation table then it will insert this date.

I don't know how to select all the dates of donor (111) and then match this date from the new date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if there is already a specified date corresponding to a specific donor_nic, use

`SELECT COUNT(date) > 0 FROM DONATION WHERE donor_nic="111" AND date="your date";`

This should return `true` if "your date" is already specified for that donor_nic.

Comment: $sql99="SELECT COUNT(lastdonationdate) > 0 FROM DONATION WHERE donor_nic='$rs' AND lastdonationdate='$date'";

$res5=mysql_query($sql99, $con);
if($res5 == $_REQUEST['lastdonationdate'])  {echo "insert"} esle {"update"}

Comment: how about `if ($res5 === "true") {echo "insert";} else {echo "update";}`

Comment: thnx @ultimateBlob.. its working now just by a little change .. :)